# From SELinux denials, how can we map the exact line of source code that caused the denial

Tags: android, linux, selinux, seandroid

I am working on Android, and we have kept SELinux in permissive mode ( development stage). We see many SELinux denials from various domains. Would like to know, if there is a way to map the denial to the exact line of code that caused the denial. This would help fellow developers, who are not familiar with SELinux but have to do code changes for the denials.